# Width and MaxWidth properties not working for WPF ColumnDefinitions

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am working with on an application that I am Dragging and Dropping Items, and creasting grids dynamically based on the contents of the objects I am dropping(some objects will require me to create a grid with 2 columns, some with 4,etc). This is simple enough to do, but when I try to specify how wide I would like these columns to be, it is not working, and it is showing the grids on top of eachother. I will attach what the columns look like.

The first example shows the result of 5 objects being dragged and dropped. You can see that the the width specification has no effects.
[image]

The second example is the same thing, but shows that the grids are not following the width specifications. When I go to drop an "Email" object onto the "Zip" object, it overlays the grids.
[image]

Here is the code that I am using to create the definitions. As you can see for each Item I iterate over, I am creating a label for.

```
                /*Initialize Grid Layout*/
                Grid newGrid = new Grid();
                newGrid.MinHeight = 40;

                /*Define Column Definitions*/
                List<ColumnDefinition> columns = new List<ColumnDefinition>  (fieldItemList.Count);
                foreach (ColumnDefinition column in columns)
                {
                    ColumnDefinition labelColumn = new ColumnDefinition();

                    /*Specify Width Dimensions*/
                    labelColumn.Width = new GridLength(150);
                    labelColumn.MaxWidth = 200.0;
                    newGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(labelColumn);
                    newGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
                }

                /*Define Row Definitions*/
                RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
                newGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
```

How do I get it to respect the width boundaries I am assigning to the column definitions?

Comment: Hard to understand how your code fits with your screenshots, but are you sure that your ColumnDefinitions aren't stretching? It could be that the Children of the Grid aren't stretching. Try to turn on GridLines for the Grid with `newGrid.ShowGridLines = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that your actual code?  If so, I don't think you are adding any columns to the grid.

```
  List<ColumnDefinition> columns = new List<ColumnDefinition>  (fieldItemList.Count);
  foreach (ColumnDefinition column in columns)
            {
```

In the above code, the columns object is being initialized with a capacity of fieldItemList.Count but doesn't contain any ColumnDefinition objects.

Comment: you are correct, the List definition is not accomplishing anything at this point, it is only being used for iteration purposes. Although this doesn't solve my problem, you did point out a some of my code that is serving no purpose. Thanks

Comment: @CitadelCSAlum, my point is that you iterating on an empty collection doesn't do anything!  Since you aren't adding any columns, you can't expect them to set a column width!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `newGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;`

If the Grid is set to stretch and has only fixed width columns it doesn't have anything to fill the remaining space it needs to fill. You could also add an extra * sized column to take up any remaining space.

Comment: I do not think this is the problem. A grid that is set to stretch should not stretch a fixed-width column.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding (2 * fieldItemList.Count) columns. I don't think you should be adding the columns in the loop... try defining the `Grid` first in XAML and then porting it to C#.